# Creating osm2pgsql hstore tags using PostGIS column

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

This is the opposite question to this one: [Creating columns in PostGIS using osm2pgsql hstore tags](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10243/creating-columns-in-postgis-using-osm2pgsql-hstore-tags)

First, I changed default.style to make separate 'lanes' column. Then I extracted osm database using osm2pgsql with --hstore.
Now I want to have 'lanes' column moved to tags instead of separate column. How to do this?

Will simple

```
UPDATE table 
SET tags->'lanes' = lanes;
```

work?
After this I would like to restore default.style to default (without lanes column), so that next data will be extracted in my desired form.

Comment: Maybe related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88295/how-to-make-osm2pgsql-import-a-tag and https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/322889/how-to-get-number-of-lane-from-osm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add a key to an existing `hstore` column, you need to concatenate the current value and to add the new value. Keeping in mind that the current hstore column may be empty, you should handle this case. At last, do the update only for rows containing a `lane` value.

This [tutorial](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-hstore/) on `hstore` is useful.

```sql
UPDATE mytable
SET tags = COALESCE(tags, hstore('')) || hstore('lanes', lanes) 
WHERE lanes IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: What does ```hstore('')``` return? I assume this is used because of possibility of empty hstore column and I think that it creates an empty hstore?

Comment: @kujaw exactly. If the column is currently null, it first creates an empty hstore and then concatenate the lane entry